# Unable to render to framebuffer (texture)

Tags: javascript, webgl, render-to-texture

I'm trying to implement shadows using shadow maps, so I need to render a scene to a separate framebuffer (texture). I cannot get it to work properly, so after stripping down my codebase I'm left with a relatively simple set of instructions which should render a scene to a texture, and then simply render the texture.

The program consists of two programs:

1. Ground program
2. Teapot program

The first should render a rectangle, with a certain texture. The second one should render a teapot (with colors based on its position). Eech render step does the following (well, that's the idea anyway):

1. Switch to framebuffer
2. Render teapot
3. Switch to normal buffer
4. Render teapot
5. Render ground

Now, the ground fragment shader looks like:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(shadowMap, fTexCoord);
```

'shadowMap' is the texture I render to in step 2. I *expect* to see a floating teapot with a rectangle drawn under it. That indeed works. Now, I also expect to have the 'ground' to contain a teapot. After all, we rendered the scene we are looking at without the ground to the framebuffer/texture.

Code

```js
var UNSIGNED_SHORT_SIZE = 2;

// Variables filled by setup()
var glCanvas;
var gl, teapotProgram, groundProgram;
var vBuffer, iBuffer, fBuffer;
var vertices, indices, textures;

var teapot = null;
var model;
var view;
var light;
var projection;

var BASE_URL = "https://hmbastiaan.nl/martijn/webgl/W08P02_SO/";

var WIDTH = 150, HEIGHT = 150;

function makeTeapot(){
    var drawingInfo = teapot.getDrawingInfoObjects();
    var indices = drawingInfo.indices;

    for(var i=0; i < indices.length; i++){
        indices[i] += 4; // Add offset for 'ground'
    }

    return {
        indices: drawingInfo.indices,
        vertices: drawingInfo.vertices
    }
}

function makeRectangle(x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2){
    var x1 = -2,
        x2 =  2,
        y1 = -1,
        y2 = -1,
        z1 = -1,
        z2 = -5;

    var vertices = [
        vec4(x1, y2, z1, 1),
        vec4(x2, y1, z1, 1),
        vec4(x2, y1, z2, 1),
        vec4(x1, y2, z2, 1)
    ];

    var textures = [
        vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
        vec2( 1.0, -1.0),
        vec2( 1.0,  1.0),
        vec2(-1.0,  1.0)
    ];

    var indices = [
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3
    ];

    return {
        indices: indices,
        vertices: vertices,
        textures: textures
    }

}

function resetBuffers(){
    vertices = [];
    indices = [];
    textures = [];

    // Add rectangle
    var rectangle = makeRectangle();
    Array.prototype.push.apply(vertices, rectangle.vertices);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(indices, rectangle.indices);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(textures, rectangle.textures);

    // Add teapot
    var teapot = makeTeapot();
    Array.prototype.push.apply(vertices, teapot.vertices);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(indices, teapot.indices);

    console.log(vertices);
    console.log(indices);
    console.log(textures);

    // Send to GPU
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function setup(){
    $.get(BASE_URL + "teapot.obj", function(teapot_obj_data){
        teapot = new OBJDoc(BASE_URL + "teapot.obj");

        if(!teapot.parse(teapot_obj_data, 1)){
            alert("Parsing teapot.obj failed.");
            return;
        }

        setup2();
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("Getting teapot.obj failed.");
    });
}

function setup2(){
    glCanvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(glCanvas, {stencil: true, alpha: false});
    gl.viewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    teapotProgram = initShaders(gl, BASE_URL + "vshader-teapot.glsl", BASE_URL + "fshader-teapot.glsl");
    groundProgram = initShaders(gl, BASE_URL + "vshader-ground.glsl", BASE_URL + "fshader-ground.glsl");

    light = vec3(0.0, 2.0, -2.0);
    view = lookAt(vec3(0, 0, 3), vec3(0,0,0), vec3(0,1,0));
    projection = perspective(45, 1.0, 1, 100.0);

    // Get teapot uniforms
    gl.useProgram(teapotProgram);
    teapotProgram.modelLoc      = gl.getUniformLocation(teapotProgram, "Model");
    teapotProgram.viewLoc       = gl.getUniformLocation(teapotProgram, "View");
    teapotProgram.projectionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(teapotProgram, "Projection");

    // Upload uniforms
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(teapotProgram.projectionLoc, false, flatten(projection));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(teapotProgram.viewLoc, false, flatten(view));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(teapotProgram.modelLoc, false, flatten(scalem(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)));

    // Get teapot attributes
    teapotProgram.vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(teapotProgram, "vPosition");

    // Get ground uniforms
    gl.useProgram(groundProgram);
    groundProgram.modelLoc      = gl.getUniformLocation(groundProgram, "Model");
    groundProgram.viewLoc       = gl.getUniformLocation(groundProgram, "View");
    groundProgram.projectionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(groundProgram, "Projection");
    groundProgram.shadowMap     = gl.getUniformLocation(groundProgram, "shadowMap");

    // Get ground attributes
    groundProgram.vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation(groundProgram, "vTexCoord");
    groundProgram.vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(groundProgram, "vPosition");

    // Allocate and fill vertices buffer
    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(teapotProgram.vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(teapotProgram.vPosition);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(groundProgram.vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(groundProgram.vPosition);

    // Allocate indices buffer
    iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    // Setup FBO
    fBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fBuffer);

    fBuffer.renderbuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, fBuffer.renderbuffer);
    gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 512, 512);

    fBuffer.texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, fBuffer.texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, fBuffer.texture, 0);
    gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, fBuffer.renderbuffer);

    // Sanity checking: framebuffer seems to throw now errors
    if (!gl.isFramebuffer(fBuffer)) {
        throw("Invalid framebuffer");
    }

    var status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
    switch (status) {
        case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
            break;
        case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
            throw("Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT");
            break;
        case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
            throw("Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT");
            break;
        case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS:
            throw("Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS");
            break;
        case gl.FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
            throw("Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED");
            break;
        default:
            throw("Incomplete framebuffer: " + status);
    }

    // Set ground textures
    gl.uniform1i(groundProgram.shadowMap, 0);

    // Upload uniforms
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(groundProgram.projectionLoc, false, flatten(projection));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(groundProgram.viewLoc, false, flatten(view));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(groundProgram.modelLoc, false, flatten(mat4()));

    // Restore default buffers
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

    // Set background colour
    gl.clearColor(0.3921, 0.5843, 0.9294, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    resetBuffers();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function render(){
    var teapot = makeTeapot();

    gl.useProgram(teapotProgram);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Switch to framebuffer
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fBuffer);

    // Draw teapot
    teapot = makeTeapot();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, teapot.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 6 * UNSIGNED_SHORT_SIZE);

    // Set framebuffer to defualt buffer (in-browser output)
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

    // Draw ground
    gl.useProgram(groundProgram);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Render teapot
    gl.useProgram(teapotProgram);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, teapot.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 6 * UNSIGNED_SHORT_SIZE);
}

setup();
```

```html
<div>
    <br/>
    <canvas width="150" height="150" id="gl-canvas">Sorry :|</canvas>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://hmbastiaan.nl/martijn/webgl/angel/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://hmbastiaan.nl/martijn/webgl/angel/initShaders2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://hmbastiaan.nl/martijn/webgl/angel/MV.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://hmbastiaan.nl/martijn/webgl/angel/objParser.js"></script>
```

Functions of interest:

1. setup2(): sets up all the buffers and uniforms.
2. render(): renders the scene.

Disclaimer: this is for an assignment, although this code is simplified enough to not look like the original assignment at all :).

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and edit it into your question. No one here is going to sift through your entire code.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to cut it down more. Thanks!

Comment: I've cut down the code considerably. The render() function is now as simple and concise as I can make it and should illustrate my problem clearly. I will edit my question as well.

Comment: You shouldn't make us jump through hoops to look at your code. Put your shaders in the code or in the html. Don't download them from an external site. That makes it super tedious to look at them :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance there are several issues.

1. Texture bindings are global. Since in setup2 you unbind the 1 texture that means it's never used.

   You need to bind whatever textures are needed before each draw call. In other words when you draw the ground you need to bind the teapot texture as in

   ```
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, fBuffer.texture);
   ```

   Note: This is an over simplification of what's really needed. You really need to

   1. Choose a texture unit to bind the texture to

      ```
      var unit = 5;
      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
      ```
   2. Bind the texture to that unit.

      ```
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, fBuffer.texture);
      ```
   3. Set the uniform sampler to that texture unit

      ```
      gl.uniform1i(groundProgram.shadowMap, unit);
      ```

   The reason you don't need those extra steps is because (a) you only
   have 1 texture so you're using texture unit #0, the default and (b) because
   uniforms default to 0 so `shadowMap` is looking at texture unit #0.
2. Because you've made a mipmapped texture just rendering to level 0 will not update the mips.

   In other words after you render the teapot you'll have a teapot in mip level 0 but mip levels 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc will still have nothing in them. You need to call

   ```
   gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D)
   ```

   For that texture after you've rendered the teapot to it. Either that or stop using mips
3. You need to set the viewport every time you call `gl.bindFramebuffer`.

   `gl.bindFramebuffer` should almost always be followed by a call to `gl.viewport` to make the viewport match the size of the thing you're rendering to

   ```
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
   // set to size of fb
   gl.viewport(0, 0, widthOfFb, heightOfFb);

   renderSomething();

   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
   // set to size of canvas's drawingBuffer
   gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
   ```
4. Attributes settings are global

   You setup the teapot attributes. Then you draw a teapot to the texture. You then draw ground, but you're still using the teapot attributes.

   Just like textures you need to setup attributes before each draw call.

I'm also guessing you really should not be calling `makeTeapot` in your render function but instead it should be called in setup.

You might find [this article useful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

You should also consider [not putting properties on WebGL objects as it's arguably an anti-pattern](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html).

Also synchronous XHR requests are not cool. You're getting this message in the JavaScript console

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because
>       of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more 
>       help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I should definitely have put the shaders in the code. The synchronous XHR requests are  part of the code my university supplies. Concerning the other points: I didn't know, thank you very much. I'll test it as soon as possible.